How to check if part of a symlink goes outside a directory in posix shell
I have about 43996 symlinks in a directory and want to check if any of them at any point of their path exit that directory in a posix shell script even if the end destination falls inside the directory.
For example lets assume the following structure:
dir/.
dir/file
dir/link -> ../dir/file

Here dir/link ends up on a file inside dir but exits the directory to get there and this is what I want to detect.
What I would have done is print the full path of the location of the link with the contents of the link appended, use tr to cut the individual parts of the symlink and pipe it to a while read loop to somehow parse it but this sounds way too slow. I want to be able to run this operation in a few seconds on all the 43996 links.
I guess I could write a C program and pipe the above text before the tr but I would prefer to keep it to POSIX shell and utilities if possible.
Can you think of anything better?

Does an absolute path count? link -> /some/path/dir/file

Out of the box approach would be to rename/bindmount the directory randomly, then check for broken links or realpath outside the random directory name (or chroot but it allows surplus ../). Otherwise parse it yourself, perhaps using some heuristic to narrow down candidates (if it does not start with /, and does not contain .. elements other than starting with at most subdir-level of ../, it might be fine, otherwise it needs a closer look).

@muru There should be no absolute paths, I will add a check for that too.

@frostschutz that's actually how I originally came up with the need for the test, I accessed the data inside dir from a different name directory (zfs snapshot) and things broke. After a bit of thought I think your idea could work, I will link the top level data in another temporary directory in /tmp (I don't want to use root) and check for broken links before and after. Quite clever!

What if there's link -> otherlink/file and otherlink is a symlink with components outside of dir?

@StéphaneChazelas You're right, my solution doesn't work at all since the kernel resolves whatever symlink I make in /tmp first so all links would work. The solution frostschutz gave works with bindmount or renaming but I don't want to require root access and I also can't rename the dir. I'm back to parsing the symlink data myself...

You could adapt my pathlld script (https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld), a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects. It recursively walks a path; and you could look at each component.

What does find dir -lname '[/.]*' say?  (Do you have dir/sub1/link42 -> ../sub2/file42, and what do you want to do with it?)

This is not an easy task because the basic tools you have to work with do either too little or too much.

Symbolic link resolution inside the kernel can only tell you the ultimate location of a chain of links. It won't tell you if the chain temporarily goes outside of a particular directory tree.
Reading a link's target with readlink is only a small part of the job as soon as .. is involved: if dir/link points to sub/../foo and sub itself is a symbolic link, the exact location of the target of sub determines whether that link is acceptable.

However, with commonly available tools, you can make a rehomed view of the directory tree, which solves most of the problem. (This was suggested by
frostschutz in a comment.) You can make a view of a directory tree with a bind mount, and you can make a bind mount with bindfs without root permissions. You just need permission to use FUSE.
The following code sets up $view to present the same content as /path/to/dir, but at a different location. The name of the toplevel is randomly generated and has a won't-happen-in-the-universe's-lifetime probability of having ever been written down before, so you can be confident that no symbolic link has that directory's name as a substring.
view=$(mktemp -d /tmp/viewXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
bindfs -n /path/to/dir "$view"
… work under $view
fusermount -u "$view"
rmdir "$view"

Any symbolic chain that starts under $view and escapes it won't be able to get back into it, since it doesn't contain the name of the toplevel directory of $view. Therefore a symbolic link is acceptable if and only if, when looking at it under $view, its fully-resolved target is still under $view. By fully-resolved target, I mean after expanding all symbolic links — this is the ultimate destination of the link except for a broken link.
For a non-broken link, you can check whether the target is within the bindfs filesystem. With POSIX shell tools, use df -P and check that the first column of the second line contains $view. With POSIX system calls, check the st_dev field contains the same value as for $view itself. You can also check that with stat(1) if your system has it.
For broken links, POSIX isn't helpful. GNU and BSD have a readlink utility that prints the fully-resolved target of a link with readlink -f: check if that starts with $view/. The following code snippet lists all the escaping links, broken or not:
cd "$view"
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'case $(readlink -f "$0") in $PWD/*) :;; *) printf %s\\n "$0";; esac' {} \;


Thanks a lot for your time, I really like your answer and while I would prefer to not require FUSE and bindfs it's an acceptable compromise. I wanted to say two things, first it might be worth mentioning that it's possible to run the two checks you mentioned both on the original and the bind mount and as long as the names are different, the results are 100% correct (referring to the won't-happen-in-the-universe's-lifetime probability). Also did you mean the sixth column of df -P i.e. the "Mounted on" field?

Note that there's now a readlink utility in the 2024 edition of the POSIX standard (just released), with -n (to not print the trailing newline, not useful) the only supported option. Though there's also realpath for readlink -f.

@Tim_Kritikos You can compare either the first column (filesystem) or the last column (mount point) in df -P. (Not the whole line because the amount of used space might change while you're gathering the data.)
